# Doctrine : how to make a nested query with the query builder?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-query

Good evening

I'm still a **junior** in SQL queries and the Doctrine query builder.
My problem is simple, so simple that I've been searching for a few hours.

I'm in a symfony 4.4 LTS project.
I have a table that represents the orders placed on an e-commerce website. There are 4 fields: id, custommer_id, created_at, status

What I want please:

the last 20 past orders that have the status = 'new' with ID descendant

If I make a SQL query

```
SELECT *
FROM order o
WHERE o.status = 'new'.
ORDER BY o.created_at DESC, o.id DESC
limit 20
```

It's a failure because I don't get the ids in descending order. I still have trouble understanding why.

Finally I found this solution in SQL:

```
   SELECT * 
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT * 
            FROM order o 
            WHERE o.status = 'new'. 
            ORDER by created_at DESC 
            LIMIT 20 
        ) table_order
        ORDER by id DESC
```

Cool!! I'm getting the last 20 commands by descending ID.

Now I have to do it with Doctrine's createQueryBuilder.
I tried a lot of solutions without success.
Can you please help me?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Entity class has the name `Order`:

```
$orders = $entityManager
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->from(Order::class, 'o')
    ->select('o')
    ->where('o.status = :newStatus')
    ->setParameter('newStatus', 'new')
    ->orderBy('o.created_at', 'DESC')
    ->addOrderBy('o.id', 'DESC')    
    ->getQuery()
    ->setMaxResults(20)
    ->getResult();
```

But with DQL it's even nicer:

```
$orders = $entityManager
    ->createQuery('
        SELECT o 
        FROM App\Entity\Order o
        WHERE o.status = :newStatus
        ORDER BY 
            o.created_at DESC AND
            o.id DESC
    ')
    ->setParameters(['newStatus' => 'new'])
    ->setMaxResults(20)
    ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the last 20 orders by `date` or by `id` is just about the same...

The later the order, the bigger the id.

If an order made at `10:32:17` have the id `59`,
then an order made after this one, lets say at `10:32:29`,
will obvilously get the id `60`.

Unless you got so many orders that they happen in the same second,
ordering by eitheir `date` or `id` is the same.

Just order them by `id` :

```php
public function getLastNewOrders() {
    $qb=$this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select("order")
       ->from(Order::class, "order")
       ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq("order.status", "new")
       ->orderBy("order.id", "DESC")
       ->setMaxResults(20);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: @SamMumm should it matter? He use ID, not UUID. And in itself, the solution is simple, sort by date instead

Comment: It is a matter of taste. IMHO the proper way is to check for createdAt

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your clear answers.
I wasn't precise enough in my post.
To put it in context, this is in the context of a technical test for my first job.

I received a symfo project with fixtures.
When I run the fixtures, I get very inconsistent data in the 'Order' table. That is to say that the logic you propose Preciel in the choice of sorting by ID or created_At can't be retained.
Let me explain:

Look at the last 9 commands in the Order table. Look at the IDs, they are in a very incoherent order.
Is this done expressly to make the test more complex? I don't know.

[image: table order]
!

If I reduce the last 5 orders of the table order with the status= 'new', I get this:

[image: table order]
!

And I'm asked to sort them by descending ID, so I want to get this:

[image: table order]
!

So the solutions you proposed do not rank in descending ID order.

goulash:
You proposed this to me:

```
$orders = $entityManager
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->from(Order::class, 'o')
    ->select('o')
    ->where('o.status = :newStatus')
    ->setParameter('newStatus', 'new')
    ->orderBy('o.created_at', 'DESC')
    ->addOrderBy('o.id', 'DESC')    
    ->getQuery()
    ->setMaxResults(20)
    ->getResult();
```

I get that, so it's not good.

[image: table order]
!

with a sql request like this, it's good:

```
  SELECT * 
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT * 
            FROM order o 
            WHERE o.status = 'new'. 
            ORDER by created_at DESC 
            LIMIT 20 
        ) table_order
        ORDER by id DESC
```

But I can't do it with the querybulder.

Thank you very much for your time.